# How many levels should I remove from a 14th level Witch if I want to add 5 Mythic Tiers to her?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, balance

Let's say I have a 14th level witch planned as the the BBEG for a campaign, but decide I need Augmented Mythic Deep Slumber (multi-year duration, only dispelled by mythic effects) for plot reasons so I have to give her 5 mythic tiers so that she can cast it.

Now, I want the campaign to finish at about the same level and I don't want to give the PCs any mythic tiers of their own.  How many levels should I remove from the witch to be a good challenge for the 10-12th level PC party I expect at the finale (i.e. to make the final encounter with her in a location she has time to set up defenses in and wherein she will be aided by some much lower CR cannon-fodder minions Encounter Level 14-16).

I don't know what the big breakpoints in Mythic are, or how they interact with breakpoints in level.  How many levels should I remove from the witch to (roughly) balance things?

Comment: This is way too broad.  This would be the equivalent of asking "I'm adding 5 class levels to a 14th level witch, what level should the witch be to stay a challenge for a level 10-12 party".  The answer depends so heavily on exactly what abilities you're giving the witch that this can't really be answered without a lot more specificity.

Comment: It also feels like you're latching on to a single, extremely specific solution to your problem.  Is there a reason you can't use a homebrewed long-duration sleep spell?

Answer (score 3):

**That's way too vague a question.**

If you are building a BBEG, you can build them the way you want.  You can make a 14th level character super effective or super ineffective in combat based on how much you CharOp them or take abilities that are just color. You might as well say "My BBEG is a fighter, what level does he need to be?" Well if all his feats are Skill Focus, 20! There's no magic level or level+tier that is the right answer, it's about coming up with a build that will be the right challenge level for your PCs.

But even more than that, you never have to be "RAW compliant" with a bad guy you're creating.  Some goddess gave her the ability to cast a single augmented mythic deep slumber, done. Worrying about this is a phenomenal waste of time and effort that would be better put into making your game rock for your players.

**Some RAW leads**

Assuming you don't like those answers, here's some mechanical leads for you to pull on.

Mythic tiers are not necessarily permanent.  They can be, but the mythic rules specifically allow for temporary granting of mythic power and then having it go away again. Since you don't seem to have much of a grasp of the mythic rules, this might be the safest course, and she's just a level 14 witch again.

Use an [Apple of Eternal Sleep](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/apple-of-eternal-sleep) or similar, so it doesn't have to be her power specifically. (Sure they could hire a high level caster to wish it away, but then again why can't they hire some mythic guy to mythic it away?  You're the DM, you control availability in the world in both cases.)

Comment: " you never have to be "RAW compliant" with a bad guy you're creating" True, you can always exercise your radical freedom.  But that certainly doesn't mean its a good idea to violate that RAW or even that it's morally permissible. [obligatory](http://existentialcomics.com/comic/17) [comic](http://existentialcomics.com/comic/58) [links](http://existentialcomics.com/comic/72)

Comment: "You're the DM, you control availability" I thought that was what was rogues were for in Pathfinder?  Or would you just GM Fiat that the rogue doesn't get to use any of his item availability altering class abilities for this arc?

Comment: Are you saying the rogue is going to steal them a wish spell?